# How to navigate a UTF-8 text file

Tags: c, parsing, utf-8

I have a text file in UTF-8 that I need to navigate in C. I need to split this file into seperate smaller files (i.e. cut it in half). When this happens, it sometimes splits the multi-byte characters into two different files. When a dumb text editor goes to read the file containing the second half of text, it reads the second half of the cut character and becomes confused, thus not displaying the rest of the text correctly. If I read byte-by-byte, how can I tell if I am at the beginning of a character or in the middle? Non-ascii compatible UTF-8 characters all start with the leading bit set to 1 but some are two bytes and some are three bytes.

Edit: Nevermind, I just found out that the first byte contains the number of leading 1s that the character is long. IE a three byte character is 1110xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx.

Comment: So... advance until you hit a leading byte?!

Comment: Splitting it at a line terminator would be wise, `'\n'`.

Comment: By the way, just splitting at codepoint boundaries will not work either. If the split occurs in between combining characters (say, a letter and a diacritic, or in the middle of a Hangul sequence, you'll also get rendering problems.

Comment: @rici: Yes, but it would still yield valid, albeit unwieldy, UTF-8 files.

Comment: @R..: valid, yes. But they might not display correctly, which was part of the question as I understood it. Perhaps "will not work" was too extreme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ((*s & 0xc0) == 0x80) /* You are in the middle of */;
```

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 characters are represented use 1 to 4 bytes.

Check a byte, if you have this binary pattern:

```
10xxxxxx
```

you are in the middle of a multi-byte. And you should continue to the next leading character.

If you have this:

```
0xxxxxxx
```

you have a 1-byte character.

```
 110xxxxx
```

is the leading byte of a 2-byte character

```
 1110xxxx
```

is the leading byte of a 3-byte character

and

```
 11110xxx
```

is the leading byte of a 4-byte character

Answer (score 1):

All UTF-8 characters are made of a leading byte and zero or more continuation bytes. All continuation bytes are of the form "10xxxxxx" in binary. So all leading bytes are of one of the two forms: "0xxxxxxx" or "11xxxxxx".